# NUMPY: What does np.empty(()) do in 2D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, random

**What does np.empty(()) actually do?**

For instance, if I want to make an empty array of 5 rows and 5 cols, I would use `np.empty((5,5))`. This gives a random output like:

```
[[0.57061489 0.57883359 0.5746548  0.57756612 0.57587218]
 [0.62539185 0.62139618 0.62313292 0.62097162 0.62221129]
 [0.70896235 0.57620393 0.73345734 0.53891594 0.75331689]
 [0.72820808 0.56994986 0.78769608 0.47609684 0.8334235 ]
 [0.62921645 0.70930812 0.6068869  0.74827839 0.55498477]]
```

**1. Why does it give a random output between 0-1 instead of generating values from the memory 
-like 7.6662e-301, 5.3767e-301..... etc?**

If I run the code `np.empty((5,5))` again in a new file, I get the same output as above. **Why is that?**

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) specify *"Array of uninitialized (arbitrary) data of the given shape"*. On my machine I get `array([[1.40031700e-311, 1.40037027e-311, 1.37961641e-306, etc`. The values are likely just the representation of whatever used to be in that memory address, casted to `float`.

Comment: @CoryKramer Yeah that might be the case, I restarted the kernel on my machine and got these memory address values. Previously I equated my empty array with another array. So it took those values into its' memory address. Okay, Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `np.empty` unless you intend to set **every** element in some way or other.  That's the implication of the **arbitrary**.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I actually wanted to set those elements with other....

Answer (score 0):

Array of uninitialized **(arbitrary)** data of the given shape, dtype, and order